# How can I bind serversocket to specific IP?

Tags: java, tcp, ip, serversocket, inetaddress

If I have a `String` representing an IP address (IPv4 or IPv6) how can I create a `ServerSocket` and bind to this IP without caring if the IP passed in, is IPv4 or IPv6?
I see that there is a constructor:`ServerSocket(int port, int backlog, InetAddress bindAddr)` but `InetAddress` does not seem to offer any constructors and its subclasses have names specific to IPv4 and IPv6.
So how can I bind the socket to the IP?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use the factory method [`INetAddress.getByName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName-java.lang.String-). It'll figure out which subclass to use. For example:

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
// or
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("::1");

// and now you can pass it to your socket-constructor
ServerSocket sock = new ServerSocket(1234, 50, addr);
```

Comment: You mean pass in my IP and get back the object?

Comment: @Jim: Yes, exactly! I have added an example on how to use it.

Comment: just a note: The default 'backlog' is 50 :D.

Comment: another note: using `0` as backlog will use the default value

Comment: what is 'back log'?

Comment: Using "127.0.0.1" will still spawn an IPv6 server as shown by `netstat -letW` in adb shell.