# ConnectException while connecting to server through IP in Java

Tags: java, sockets

I have written a simple Client-Server program in java. when i create a socket like
`Socket socket = new Socket("localhost",7000);`

I am able to connect to the server and transfer the data(any console input) to the Server but when i pass localhost Ip(127.0.0.1) in the Socket like

```
 Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1",7000);
```

I get the following error Error:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Why i am getting this.

Here is my server side Code

```
public class SocketServer {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      new SocketServer();

        // TODO code application logic here
    }

  public   SocketServer(){

       try {
            ServerSocket sSocket = new ServerSocket(7000);
            System.out.println("Server started at: " + new Date());


//Wait for a client to connect
            Socket socket = sSocket.accept();

            //Create the streams
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            //Tell the client that he/she has connected
            output.println("You have connected at: " + new Date());

            //Loop that runs server functions
            while(true) {
                //This will wait until a line of text has been sent
                String chatInput = input.readLine();
                System.out.println(chatInput);
            }
        } catch(IOException exception) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + exception);
        }


    }
```

Here is my client side Code

```
public class ClientSocket {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
        // TODO code application logic here

        new ClientSocket();
    }
  public ClientSocket() throws UnknownHostException
    {
    //We set up the scanner to receive user input
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        try {
           //Socket socket = new Socket("localHost",7000);//works Fine
            Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1",7000);//Gives error
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            //This will wait for the server to send the string to the client saying a connection
            //has been made.
            String inputString = input.readLine();
            System.out.println(inputString);
            //Again, here is the code that will run the client, this will continue looking for 
            //input from the user then it will send that info to the server.
            while(true) {
                //Here we look for input from the user
                String userInput = scanner.nextLine();
                //Now we write it to the server
                output.println(userInput);
            }
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + exception);
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my /etc/hosts file

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Comment: Are you able to ping 127.0.0.1? Did you try telnet? Might be a problem with your server config.

Comment: Yes i am able to ping

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976867/how-can-i-bind-serversocket-to-specific-ip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced Similar problem. Make following Changes in your Code

At Client Side

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
Socket socket = new Socket(addr,7000);
```

At Server Side

```
ServerSocket sSocket = new ServerSocket();
sSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress("0.0.0.0", 7000));
```

@Stefan has also answered right,binding to `0.0.0.0` will allow it to listen to all interfaces

Answer (score 5):

When you create a `Socket`, you bind it to a certain address. In your case, you bound it to `localhost`, which is the same as `127.0.0.1` but not the same address (while `localhost` should always resolve to `127.0.0.1`). Your application sees the connection attempt, but it also sees that it should not listen on that address so it refuses the connection.

Try binding your server socket to `127.0.0.1` or even `0.0.0.0` (with `0.0.0.0`, you're telling it to listen to all incoming connections (`127.0.0.1`, `localhost` and your LAN IP address/hostname)).

[Here's some more information about this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382602/what-is-the-difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-localhost)

After seeing your server and client, you could try the following on the server side:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 7000));
```

Comment: i have put my code for Client and server can u plz answer w.r.t that.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong constructor to create the Socket in the client.

This code:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 7000);
```

Is trying to resolve the name `"127.0.0.1"` as a DNS name. This constructor is internally doing this:

```
InetAddress.getByName(hostname);
```

If you want to connect to an IP address you have to use this constructor:

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[]{127,0,0,1});
Socket socket = new Socket(address, 7000)
```

Comment: It looks like you already have something listening in that port. your server code looks right. It will default accepting connections on any/all local addresses. Can you try to do a telnet to 127.0.0.1 7000 while your server is shutdown?

Comment: Sorry, I've found the problem. You're creating your Socket with the wrong constructor. I've updated my answer